# Set the back-office theme to a specific url

Tags: 6, theming

(On drupal 6)

On some of the websites i have to manage, the translation page of a node ( mywebsiteurl.com/node/NodeNid/translate) use the main theme instead of the back office theme.

I have some ideas about how force the back office theme, but i doubt it's the right way.

I create a specific module and use a preprocess_page function to force a

```
$GLOBALS['custom_theme'] = variable_get('theme', 'mybackofficetheme')
```

if i am in a translation page. But it doesn't works, so can you suggest me the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using translation pages, but I've had good success using the themekey module for changing themes based on URL:
https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey